# Editing the table that stores sms on android

Tags: java, android

I am reading sms in my android device using java

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

but i need to mark which sms is processed by my background service or not.Will there be any danger in editing the sqlite database table that stores the sms.

I would like to add an extra column to indicate what has been processed or what has not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify any data from SMS content provider since KitKat, see: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-sms-provider

So it is not recommended to do what you want.

Comment: Wow,thats mean.Anyway,other versions of android can allow you do that?

Comment: Apparently yes, I have not tried yet. But even if it works, your application will not work for most devices in the market. I think it is better to keep a DB inside you application with the ids of the processed messages, so you can guarantee it works in the most recent versions.